# package android.support.annotation does not exist

Tags: android

my gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gt.otomat7"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':libraries:tess-two')
}
```

But ı got an error about annotation does not exist I am using tesseract library and my android studio version

```
Android Studio 3.1.4
Build #AI-173.4907809, built on July 24, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

thank you for your helps

Answer (score 9):

The following answer solved my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56674446/643156

```
yarn add --dev jetifier
yarn run jetify
```

Answer (score 9):

Please change from:

```
android.support.annotation
```

to:

```
androidx.annotation
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using SDK version 28, change the following version from

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1"
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0"
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to your IonicWebViewEngine.java file and change from:

```
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
```

to:

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `IonicWebViewEngine.java` file and change from:

```
android.support.annotation
```

to:

```
androidx.annotation
```