# How to fix "Failed to run Jetifier" in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run my react native project but getting following error:

```
error Failed to run jetifier. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: spawnSync C:\Users\viral\StudioProjects\ReactNative\Demo\CoTask\node_modules\jetifier\bin\jetify ENOENT
at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1002:20)
at spawnSync (child_process.js:614:24)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:642:13)
at Object.runAndroid [as func] 
(C:\Users\viral\StudioProjects\ReactNative\Demo\CoTask\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:101:41)
at Command.handleAction (C:\Users\viral\StudioProjects\ReactNative\Demo\CoTask\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:21)
at Command.listener (C:\Users\viral\StudioProjects\ReactNative\Demo\CoTask\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8)
at Command.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Command.parseArgs (C:\Users\viral\StudioProjects\ReactNative\Demo\CoTask\node_modules\commander\index.js:651:12)
at Command.parse (C:\Users\viral\StudioProjects\ReactNative\Demo\CoTask\node_modules\commander\index.js:474:21)
at setupAndRun (C:\Users\viral\StudioProjects\ReactNative\Demo\CoTask\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:210:24)
```

I have already added following code in gradle.properties, but didn't worked.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235525/issues-using-androidx-and-react-native

Comment: try installing jetifier again and after that npx jetify. It should work

Comment: @Traendy I tried it, but still getting same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

temporary run with

```
react-native run-android --no-jetifier
```

Comment: But I want to jetify it. So can't use this.

Comment: Please update the **@react-native-community/cli** to the latest version.

Comment: Read this, hope this will help you https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25669

Comment: That was helpful

Answer (score 0):

For me just doing this worked:
`npm install --save-dev jetifier`

Then `npx jetify`